# How can I align emoji with text in table cell?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add an Emoji Unicode to my td row and getting it in front of the numbers I select from the database. For some reason I can not get it to go in front of my text. I am hoping that someone here know what is going wrong.

The question: How do i get the Emoji Unicode in one line with the rest of the text (in this case so it spawns in front of the numbers).

I do not know how to add a image here to show what it is like now. But to describe it. The emoji is first and puts the text(numbers in this case) underneath it.

```
<table align="left" class="deftable" style="margin-bottom:20px; width:285px !important;">
    <tr>
    <td style="width:275px !important;">Banana's in store: </td><td style="display:inline-block; ">
&#127820;<?= htmlspecialchars(number_format($obj['bananas'],0,",",".")) ?></td></td></tr> </table>
```

Comment: PHP tag removed as this only involves HTML and CSS

Comment: You have two problems: you have an extra `</td>` in there. And the actual problem is your table is 285 px wide and the first column is 275px wide. Which means you are expecting the emoji and price to fit in 10px of space. You will need to either make the first column smaller or the overall table wider.